# Retrieving JSON from a PHP file with JSON content type

Tags: php, json

This might seem like a dumb question but after a long search, I'm stumped.

I'm using a query to retrieve data then encoding to JSON for use in various places around my site. There's just one issue. I can't seem to retrieve the data!

Query (data.users.php):

```
$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT
    CONCAT(m.firstName,' ',m.lastName) AS name,
    m.email,
    m.permission,
    m.costRate,
    m.dt,
    m.memberID,
    m.moduleFinancial,
    o.orgName

    FROM members m

    LEFT JOIN organisations o ON m.organisationID = o.organisationID
    WHERE status = 'true'
    ORDER BY name"
) or die(mysql_error());

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}
header("Content-type: application/json");

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Example of the data:

```
[{"name":"Admin User","email":"test@test.com","permission":"admin","dt":"2013-02-02 10:26:29","memberID":"M0000001"},{"name":"Another User","email":"another@test.com","permission":"admin","dt":"2012-02-02 10:26:29","memberID":"M0000002"}]
```

Any ideas?

Updated fetch code:

```
ob_start();
            include("../data/data.users.php");
            $arr = json_decode(ob_get_clean(), true);

            foreach($arr as $item) {
                if ($item['memberID'] == $_GET["ID"]) {
                    $user_name = $item['name'];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes, that is normal - JSON is supposed to have a lack of whitespace in order to be as compact as possible.

Comment: In that case, any idea what's the matter with the code that displays the data?

Comment: I think @fab has got it with his answer below.

Comment: Hey guys, please see the edited question. I've added additional detail.

Answer (score 2):

PHP >= 5.4 has JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option as documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php to get nicely formatted JSON string:

```
json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, your problem lies somewhere else, `json_decode` does not need line breaks. However, I found this line suspicious:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("../data/data.users.php"),true);
```

you want to read a PHP script as JSON? This is *source code*, nothing gets executed there!

**Update:**

It's exactly like I suspected: you read the PHP file and pass it to `json_decode`. The PHP source code is not valid JSON, thus it returns `null`. `file_get_contents` would only be possible with the http wrapper:

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com/data/data.users.php")
```

but that's unnecessary complicated and generally not a good idea. Also, the script would have to be under the public web directory. You should **include** `data.users.php`. For this, you have two options:

1. change `echo` to `return` and then use:

   ```
   $arr = json_decode(include("../data/data.users.php"), true);
   ```
2. use output buffering:

   ```
   ob_start();
   include("../data/data.users.php");
   $arr = json_decode(ob_get_clean(), true);
   ```

The first option should be the preferred one, however, if you cannot change `data.users.php` for some reason, the second one is a valid workaround.

**P.S.:** you might want to get rid of the call to `header()` too, if `data.users.php` will not be called directly over the web. Otherwise, remember to override the content-type header in your second script if it does not deliver JSON to the browser/client.

Comment: Additional detail added above.

Comment: Thanks Fab, it's working on a test page. Phew! Just one more problem. When I add the code to the actual page the include breaks the page. I've added the amended code above.

Comment: What do you mean with "break"? Did you read my note about `header('Content-type:...')`?

Comment: Unfortunately I need the header to allow the data to be read by Kendo UI which is running in other areas of the site. When I say 'not working' I mean that when I call the page this code lives on, nothing displays. Remove the include or more the code below some text (for instance), the text displays just fine. Thanks for your help BTW. It's people like you that drive this place!

Comment: There could be different reasons, but you should try to remove the header call, just to see if it makes a difference. If so, make sure that nothing gets outputted before the include and call `header('Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8`);` (or whatever you need) after it, to override the JSON header. Also, enable error_reporting for development! A blank page usually means an error, if you allow PHP to display or log it, you will be wiser ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this dear....

Input

```
{"key1":[1,2,3],"key2":"value"}
```

Output

```
    {
    "key1": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "key2": "value"
}
```

Function Code :

```
    function prettyPrint( $json )
{
    $result = '';
    $level = 0;
    $prev_char = '';
    $in_quotes = false;
    $ends_line_level = NULL;
    $json_length = strlen( $json );

    for( $i = 0; $i < $json_length; $i++ ) {
        $char = $json[$i];
        $new_line_level = NULL;
        $post = "";
        if( $ends_line_level !== NULL ) {
            $new_line_level = $ends_line_level;
            $ends_line_level = NULL;
        }
        if( $char === '"' && $prev_char != '\\' ) {
            $in_quotes = !$in_quotes;
        } else if( ! $in_quotes ) {
            switch( $char ) {
                case '}': case ']':
                    $level--;
                    $ends_line_level = NULL;
                    $new_line_level = $level;
                    break;

                case '{': case '[':
                    $level++;
                case ',':
                    $ends_line_level = $level;
                    break;

                case ':':
                    $post = " ";
                    break;

                case " ": case "\t": case "\n": case "\r":
                    $char = "";
                    $ends_line_level = $new_line_level;
                    $new_line_level = NULL;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if( $new_line_level !== NULL ) {
            $result .= "\n".str_repeat( "\t", $new_line_level );
        }
        $result .= $char.$post;
        $prev_char = $char;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

may this helps to you........

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode($arr)."\r\n";
```